# IntegrityError when creating a new model object

Tags: python, django, model, null

I'm getting the error:

> IntegrityError at evaluation/evaluee/new**
>
> Null value in column "Evaluation_data_id" violates not-null constraint**

I think it has to do with the way I set up the relationship with the two models.

The ideia is: every time one EvaluationModel is created, an EvaluatorModel object should be created too (getting some values such as evaluee and evaluator) from the first model.

I created an evaluation_data field so that I could access EvaluationModel

My model:

```
class EvaluationModel(models.Model):
    evaluee = models.ForeignKey(
        get_user_model(),
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name= '+',
        verbose_name='Evaluee',
    )
    evaluator = models.ForeignKey(
        get_user_model(),
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name= '+',
        verbose_name='Evaluator',
    )
    dgl = models.ForeignKey(
        get_user_model(),
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name= '+',
        verbose_name='DGL',
    )
   
    # (...)

    def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
        created = not self.pk
        super().save(*args,**kwargs)
        if created:
            EvaluatorModel.objects.create(evaluee = self.evaluee, evaluator = self.evaluator, dgl = self.dgl, currentrole = self.currentrole,tenure = self.tenure)

class EvaluatorModel(models.Model):
    #evaluator
    evaluee = models.CharField(null = True, blank = True, max_length=50)
    evaluator = models.CharField(null = True, blank = True, max_length=50)
    
    evaluation_data = models.OneToOneField(
        EvaluationModel,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        primary_key= True,
        related_name="evaluationdata",
        default = "",
        db_constraint=False,
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.evaluee + '-' + self.evaluator
```

Comment: It means that you did not specify a value for `evaluation_data`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `save` method, you make the following call:

```
EvaluatorModel.objects.create(evaluee = self.evaluee, 
                              evaluator = self.evaluator, 
                              dgl = self.dgl, 
                              currentrole = self.currentrole,
                              tenure = self.tenure)
```

but does not specify a value for `evaluation_data`. Add

```
evaluation_data = self
```

along with the arguments to fix this.

If `evaluation_data` is not needed, you may also add `null=True` to its definition   and and avoid that objects created from other places (where you still might not have an `EvaluationModel` instance yet created) raise the same Error.